# Why does chrome driver not launch chrome?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I am attempting to code an account creator bot for instagram, and I have all of the necessary information now (email, password, username are automatically generated on every run). But all of a sudden it stopped opening chrome when the code is run. I have really been struggling and I am not sure what to do. I am very new to coding, and would appreciate help. Here is the code, I did not include the code for the imports and the login info generation because I don't think that is necessary . I apologize if my formatting is poor, this is my first post. I'm using pycharm, also the chromedriver is in the source folder which is why the path is like that.

```
class CreatorBot:
    def __init__(self, email, fullname, username, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.username = username

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

        self.by = By
        self.ec = EC
        self.webDriverWait = WebDriverWait

        time.sleep(1)
        self.create()
        time.sleep(10)

    # This function is for the act of signing up.

    def create(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/')

        self.webDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            self.ec.presence_of_element_located((self.by.NAME, 'Mobile number or email')))
        self.webDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(self.ec.presence_of_element_located((self.by.NAME, 'Full Name')))
        self.webDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(self.ec.presence_of_element_located((self.by.NAME, 'Username')))
        self.webDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(self.ec.presence_of_element_located((self.by.NAME, 'Password')))
        self.webDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(self.ec.element_to_be_clickable(
            (self.by.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[7]/div/button')))

        self.driver.find_element_by_name('Mobile Number or Email').send_keys(self.email)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('Full Name').send_keys(self.fullname)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('Username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[7]/div/button').click()
```

Comment: Do you also have chrome installed in the system you trying to run on? chromedriver is just a driver, it requires chrome installed separately.

Comment: yes, I have it installed